# jQuery ajax call on ajax loaded data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a form to make a reservation on a website. When you choose a shift, the available dates are loaded. Now I'd like to load the available seats when you pick a date.

```
//Shift choosen
$("input[name$=shift]").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/reservations/date/list/future-notfull-withshift',
        data: $("input[name$='shift']").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
                $("#date").html(msg);
                $("#date").fadeIn(250);
            }
    });
});

//Date choosen
$("input[name$=dates]").live("change", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/reservations/date/list/availableseats',
        data: $("input[name$='dates']").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#seats").html(msg);
            $("#seats").fadeIn(250);
        }
    });
});
```

In this code the first block works just fine, but the second call, which is very much the same, doesn't work: No Ajax call is made ...
Any idea why? How can I solve this?

Comment: Try running it with Firebug to check that no JavaScript errors occurred and also put in an alert() in the second change handler to make sure that it is firing.

Comment: this was a bug in jQuery 1.4.0/1 , fixed in v 1.4.2. what version are you using?

Comment: Silly question: does your Jquery version supports .live() ? Has to be at least 1.3

Comment: @a'r The alert doesn't pop up, so I think the handler isn't fired ...

I'm usging version v1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that `$("input[name$=dates]")` find something. Maybe jQuery can't find your `dates` input?

BTW: is it your application? If you can - use `id` attrib or `class` attrib. `input[name$=dates]` selector is not very fast. Even scoped find is better: `$('#foo').find("input[name$=dates]").live(...)`.
Also take a look at `delegate` function in jQuery. Its like `live` but better ;)

Comment: I had input as selector and not select :-(. Thanks for the tip!